# "isdigit()" com 0.00 não funciona

Tags: python

Por que o método `isdigit()` não identifica que `0.00` é um digito? Estou trabalhando com alguns milhões de dados e certos registros possuem valores do tipo `0.0000001` ou `0.00`.

- Quando tento converter o `0.0000001` para **Decimal**, ele me retorna
  `1E-7`
- Quando valido se `"0.00".isdigit()` ele me retorna `False`.

Comment: Pelo que me lembre, `isDigit` só retornaria verdadeiro caso só existissem caracteres de sinal ou de `0-9`. No caso, o ponto/separador de decimais não é considerado assim digito.

Comment: Talvez você desejasse ver se é um número, não?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque ele não é composto só por dígitos. O ponto não é um dígito. Faça a pergunta certa que receberá a resposta certa.

```
try:
    resultado = Decimal(numero)
except ValueError:
    print('Não foi possível converter')
```

Quanto a questão da notação científica, isso só importa quando o número tiver que ser traduzido para texto - seja para impressão na tela, armazenamento em arquivo texto, inclusão num template de HTML, etc...
Nesse ponto, o número deve passar pelo método `format` - seja através dele explicitamente, seja com as novas "F-strings" do Python, ou chamando a função `format` do Python diretamente (os três métodos vão chamar o método `__format__` interno do objeto `Decimal`). E para o `format`, basta passar a formatação como "float" (letra f) para impressão do `Decimal` sem notação científica:

```
print("{:f}".format(Decimal(".00000001"))
```

ou:

```
print(format(Decimal(".00000000001"), "f"))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/IsDigit.py).

Comment: Faltou responder a segunda pergunta:
 - Quando tento converter o 0.0000001 para Decimal, ele me retorna 1E-7

Comment: Aí é questão de apresentação, número é número: https://ideone.com/HIO2La

Comment: Mas mesmo assim, pra exibir dessa forma, ele retorna uma string. Quero saber como transformar isso em Decimal ou Float sem gerar essas *notações cientificas*.

Comment: Acho que você não entende a diferença entre um número e a representação textual de um número. Um número não tem notação científica.

Comment: O cast para Decimal  `Decimal('9.99999999999999954748111825886258685613938723690807819366455078125E-8')` esta correto, no momento de exibir apenas formato o valor `0.0000001`, certo?

Comment: Entendi o que você disse nas mensagens, so estava focando em transformar e exibir no banco `0.0000001` e não `1E-7`. Valeu

Comment: Guilherme: se a resposta não está legal, e você acha que podem ter respostas melhores, você não precisa aceitar essa como correta (por isso que tem o mecanismo de upvote e  o de resposta aceita separados).
Não estar aceita não so incentiva quem respondeu a melhorar o texto, como incentiva outras pessoas a virem com outras respostas, que podem estar mais completas.

Comment: @jsbueno por outro lado se a resposta não está completa porque a pessoa não perguntou algo que queria saber, se ela quer saber outra coisa além da pergunta, deve fazer outra pergunta, caso contrário a pergunta poderá ser fechada por não estar clara ou ser ampla.

Comment: pronto - asism achoq que fica mais legal  - sem precisar ir no ideone. A pergunta dele inclui as duas dúvidas, afinal.